# Adding horizontal lines to pgfplots bar

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am using a pgfplots stacked bar to display the aggregated energy demand of a houshold and the associated price. When the energy demand exceeds a certain threshold, than a higher price has to be paid. This is visualized by the color red and blue of the bars. The threshold is displayed by the thick red horizontal line.

My problem is, that I want this red line to exceed the width of the bar, so that it's width is circa 120 percent of the width of the bar.
Is there any possibility to achieve this?
Thanks

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ymin=0,ymax=4,
  samples=3,
  enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
  bar width=0.6,
  ybar stacked,
  legend pos=south east,
    every axis/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
]

\draw[red, very thick] (axis cs:0.7,2) -- (axis cs:1.3,2);
\draw[red, very thick] (axis cs:1.7,2.5) -- (axis cs:2.3,2.5);
\draw[red, very thick] (axis cs:2.7,2.5) -- (axis cs:3.3,2.5);

\addplot
coordinates 
    {(1,1) (2,2.5) (3,1.5)};

\addplot
coordinates 
    {(1,0) (2,1) (3,0)};


\legend{low price, high price}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compute the excess width and adjust the coordinates by `10%` on each side of the drawn lines to get the lines to be `20%` wider:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\newcommand{\MyBarWidth}{0.6}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ExcessBarWitdh}{0.1*\MyBarWidth}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ymin=0,ymax=4,
  samples=3,
  enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
  bar width=\MyBarWidth,
  ybar stacked,
  legend pos=south east,
    every axis/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
]

\draw[red, very thick] (axis cs:0.7-\ExcessBarWitdh,2) -- (axis cs:1.3+\ExcessBarWitdh,2);
\draw[red, very thick] (axis cs:1.7-\ExcessBarWitdh,2.5) -- (axis cs:2.3+\ExcessBarWitdh,2.5);
\draw[red, very thick] (axis cs:2.7-\ExcessBarWitdh,2.5) -- (axis cs:3.3+\ExcessBarWitdh,2.5);

\addplot
coordinates 
    {(1,1) (2,2.5) (3,1.5)};

\addplot
coordinates 
    {(1,0) (2,1) (3,0)};


\legend{low price, high price}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```